# What are some good ways to measure the performance of a single page web app?

Tags: javascript, performance, testing

We have a single page web app and we want to measure it's performance.  There's a lot of JavaScript and AJAX on it and we want to see how long it takes to fully load up.  What are some good tools to use?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome profilers are pretty amazing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxW1dCjOstE

You can find whole bunch of tutorials on youtube showing how to inspect heap usage.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (in Firefox), [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) (in IE/Firefox), or use the Network tab (press F12) in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Consider looking at boomerang (https://github.com/soasta/boomerang), and opensource JavaScript library that measures performance while users use your site.  It can automatically measure XHR requests and also has support for frameworks like Angular, Ember & Backbone and can be extended with more plugins.

Using boomerang you will need to build your own back end infrastructure to collect and analyse the data, or you can use commercial services like SOASTA's mPulse (the boomerang developers work on this) that collect, filter, analyse and report on the data.  mPulse is available at http://www.soasta.com/mpulse/

Answer (score -1):

You can use a useful plugin developped by Yahoo "yslow".

It details the loading of all the components of your website (js, css, images, favicon, ...), then it shows you a global performance's note for your website, the worst is 0, the better 100.

What it looks like:
[image]

Source plugin: http://yslow.org/

Here you have a video where they explain how to use it: (it lasts more than 1 hour) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxW74v3h1xY

The website they use to determine all the things you can do to improve the performance of your website: http://webdevchecklist.com/